# kindly convert oracle view to postgresql

Tags: postgresql-9.5

CREATE VIEW HTWRK_AGEING_UNAGE_YYYYMM ("YEAR", "MONTH") AS SELECT YEAR, MONTH FROM (SELECT year, month FROM (SELECT TO_CHAR (n + 1994) year FROM ( SELECT LEVEL n FROM DUAL CONNECT BY ROWNUM <= TO_CHAR (SYSDATE, 'YYYY') - 1994)) a, (SELECT LPAD (n, 2, '0') month FROM ( SELECT LEVEL n FROM DUAL CONNECT BY ROWNUM <= 12)) b) WHERE year || month <= TO_CHAR (SYSDATE, 'YYYYMM') UNION SELECT 'NA', 'NA' FROM DUAL;

Comment: need support to convert into PostgreSQL.

Answer (score 0):

This is way easier in Postgres

```
create view htwrk_ageing_unage_yyyymm 
as
select to_char(dt, 'yyyy') as year,
       to_char(dt, 'mm') as month
from generate_series(date '1995-01-01', date_trunc('month', current_date), interval '1 month')
union all
select 'NA', 'NA';
```